# How to change the form encoding in Python Requests?

Tags: python, encoding, python-requests

I have a Cyrillic string that I'd like to send as form data in Windows-1251 encoding using Python Requests.

Take a look at this example:

```
import requests
st = 'Искать'
requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data={'test': st})
```

However, the data of the request becomes this (running `nc -l 8888` to view the request):

```
test=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C
```

That is my target string, encoded as UTF-8, which we can easily check:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> st = 'Искать'
>>> quote(st, encoding='utf-8')  # Matches
'%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C'
>>> quote(st, encoding='cp1251')  # Doesn't match
'%C8%F1%EA%E0%F2%FC'
```

Now I thought that if I encode the data myself, it would work just fine.

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data={'test': quote(st, encoding='cp1251')})
```

But turns out that this is not the case because while the letters are encoded, the percent signs get encoded again into UTF-8 (`%25`) and the whole string becomes invalid again

```
test=%25C8%25F1%25EA%25E0%25F2%25FC
```

So I'm looking for a way to either disable the built-in Requests' encoding feature or override the encoding value. How can I do it?

I'm using Python 3.5, Requests 2.18.4

Comment: as described in doc i try that: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: @Lupanoide that controls the encoding of the response's body, not the request's form data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs.python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> There are times that you may want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly.

So, if you don't want your data to get form-encoded you should use a string.

```
st = 'Искать'
data={'test': quote(st, encoding='cp1251')}
data = '&'.join('='.join(i) for i in data.items())
requests.post('http://localhost:8888', data=data)
```